# R: Margins too large when grid.arranging plots in two rows in grid.arrange/ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am drawing multiple maps based on a list with the following `ggplot2` custom function:

```
plot_list = list()
for (i in 1:length(input_map[[1]])) {
  p = ggplot() +
    geom_polygon(data = df_new, aes_string(x = "long.x", y = "lat.x", fill=input_map[[3]][i], 
                                group = "commune"), size=0, colour = "lightgrey") +
    geom_polygon(data = cantons_shp, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
                 size= .1, colour = "lightgrey", fill = NA) +
    coord_fixed() +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = input_map[[2]][i], name = input_map[[1]][i], na.value="white", limits=0:1) +
    labs(title = input_map[[1]][i], x = "", y = "") +
    theme_void() +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(size=10, hjust = 0.5),
          legend.position = "bottom", # c(0.85, 0.75)
          legend.text = element_text(size=7),
          legend.title = element_blank(),
          plot.background = element_rect("white"),
          plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), "cm"))
  plot_list[[i]] = as.grob(p)
}
```

When arranging 6 maps with `grid.arrange` in two rows, the maps are getting too small and there is lots of white space between the plots.

```
# grid.arrange without do.call does not work
do.call("grid.arrange", 
          c(plot_list, nrow=2, 
          top=title,
          bottom=paste0(n_recordings, " Opnamen aus ", n_communes, " Gemengen", "\nSchnëssen-Projet | (c) Universitéit Lëtzebuerg, 2019")
          )
      )
```

[image: Margins between maps too large]

In the theme options, I already reduced `plot.margin` to 0, without avail.

Comment: So what exactly is your desired output? Are you trying to reduce the space between columns? Then you just want to make your plotting device narrower otherwise grid objects always to to take up the full space you plot to. I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ah! It is really that simple than adjusting the plot window in Rstudio!? I didn't think of such an easy solution.